# Includes in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm with a problem to use the Entity Framework Core when I do a select with includes like this:

```
var protocolos = _protocoloService.Search(p => p.Active == true,
       p => p.Include(l => l.Local)
       , tracking: false).ToList();
```

The result in ajax has about 80mb.

---

But In this test:

```
var protocolos = _protocoloService.Search(p => p.Active == true, tracking: 
 false).ToList();

 foreach(Protocolo p in protocolos)
 {
       Local local = _localService.GetById(p.ID_Local).Result;
       p.Local = local;
 }
```

The result has just 500kb. 
OBS: I'm using the AsNoTracking.

Someone give me a help?